# Uniqueness of the Green's function

Tags: partial-differential-equations, mathematical-physics

Given a linear operator $L$, a Green's function $G(x,s)$ is any solution of $$\tag{1} LG(x,s) = \delta(x-s)$$
where $\delta(x-s)$ is the Dirac Delta function.

The Green's function can also be used in solving equations of the form
$$\tag{2} Lu(x) = f(x)$$

My question is, if we have any linear operator $L$, is it possible that the Green's function for that operator is unique in the sense that any function $u(x)$ and $f(x)$ be used but it would still yield the same Green's function?

$$\\$$
Let's say that we have Poisson's equation for an
 arbitrary function:
$$\nabla^2u(x) = f(x) \tag{3}$$
According to books the Green's function for this operator would be $G(r) = -\frac{1}{4\pi r}$ such that the solution for Poisson's equation would be
$$\tag{4} u(x) = \int G(x,s) f(s) \, ds$$

But is that really the case even for any value of $u(x)$ and $f(x)$?

Comment: You need "sufficiently nice" $f $.

Comment: Is that the only thing that's needed? Does the argument still hold that for an operator $L$ you'd have a Green's function $G$ such that $L_1 = G_1, \, L_2 = G_2, \, \ldots, \, L_n =  G_n$?

Comment: If the Green's function exists, then it gives the solution to the problem for all $f $ in a certain (usually large but not exhaustive) set of functions.

Comment: A quick negative would be to observe that if you add to a green's function any $v(x)$ which is annihilated by $L$ then it's still a greens function. In your special case you could add an arbitrary harmonic function to $G(r)$ and it would still be a green's function.